# Determine whether an optimization problem is a linear program

Tags: linear-programming

Can anyone help me with the following problem?

> Consider an optimization problem (P) that has two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. Here are the following facts of P:
>
> $x_1 = 3, x_2 = 6$ is a feasible solution.
>
> $x_1 = 5, x_2 = 2$ is a feasible solution.
>
> $x_1 = 4, x_2 = 4$ is NOT a feasible solution.
>
> Based on the facts above, can we determine whether (P) is a linear program?

My answer is that (P) is not a linear program. However I don't know if my answer is correct or how to justify it...

Comment: Hint: the feasible set of an LP must be convex.

Comment: Additional hint: those three points are on the same line.